# как бы это странно не звучало но visual studi 2022 стал чёрным

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

При запуске вижуала такая проблема [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам поможет информация о встроенных темах:

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2022

Также проверьте обновления в Visual Studoi Installer. В крайнем случае всегда есть животворящая переустановка...